# jquery button suddenly not working on iPhone or iPad

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, touchstart

I've tried all the suggestions I found and cannot make this button work on iPhone or iPad. It used to work a few months ago, and now it doesn't. It's fine for PCs. Have tried touchstart, and cursor:pointer; is already in CSS with no luck. Any other ideas? Go easy... I'm not actually a programmer.

HTML is:

```
echo '<td><span style="color:#fff;"  thing1="'.$thing1Id.'"  thing2="'.$row['thing2Id'].'" user="'.$user->ID.'" class="runScript btn" >Run!</span></td></tr>';


jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".runScript").on("click",function(){
    var me = jQuery(this);
    var thing1= me.attr("thing1");
    var thing2= me.attr("thing2");
    var user = me.attr("user");
    me.html("Working on it! Please wait!");
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/runScript?thing1=" + me.attr('thing1') + "&thing2=" + me.attr('thing2') + "&user=" + me.attr('user') 
    }).done(function(data) {
        me.html("Done!");
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] with actual HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".runScript", function() {

});
```

Comment: That is only necessary if the "runscript" element is not available at load time